# How do I take feedback about a bare minimum live feature?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, usability-testing

I am part of a small startup and I am new to the UX process. I have been designing for about a year without following a process or structure.

We offer MOOCs and we are looking to overhaul the video player/learning platform. We need to ask questions from existing users about their experience on the website: specifically the video player.

How should I go about this? We do not have too many users who are satisfied with the experience. We do not offer many features to begin with. We are similar to [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) but we are looking to be better, obviously.

What sort of questions should I ask?

Should I approach them via email or should I call them up?

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible you should do both: Qualitative and Quantitative research.

> Qualitative methods are much better suited for answering questions
>   about why or how to fix a problem, whereas quantitative methods do a
>   much better job answering how many and how much types of questions.

From each one you will get different insights and when combining the results it will give you a more precise answer.

You should read this article [When to Use Which User-Experience Research Methods](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/which-ux-research-methods/), by Nielsen Norman Group, to get a deeper understanding of the options you have.